# ASP.NET postback and back button

Tags: asp.net, caching, postback, back-button

Sorry if this turns out to be a dupe. I can't find anything that exactly resembles my problem.

I have an asp:label on a form. On submit button postaback, I do server-side validation. If it fails, I set the label to some text value.

If I supply valid info and click submit again, I set the label to empty as part of the submit click and it performs the postback and shows the new page.

If I click the back button, it shows the correct info in the form AND the error label.

Clicking submit again indicates the labels text property is empty, although the text is clearly visible on the screen.

I expect the label to be empty (effectively not visible) since I set it to empty before I performed any actions.

I have tried with both Text property and Visible property, but with the same result.

Ready? GO...

Comment: I am simply making use of the validation code/design that was there to avoid a lengthy code write. Now that I have blown that objective away. I could change the design to use customvalidators and a client-side script...?????

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblMessage.Visible = false;
}
```

Each time your page is loaded your message will be invisible. So, when you do your serverside validation you can set you label's text and set the Visibility = true.

Comment: yes. doesn't help. the output is already cached, so no change in the controls in the submit button click get pushed to the cache. the back button simply shows the state of the last cache.

Comment: I'm wondering if you could clear the cache when the submit button is clicked. I can't say I'm sure this will work or not, just a suggestion.. Up-voted your question.

Answer (score 0):

"If I click the back button, it shows the correct info in the form AND the error label." : no problem with this ; it shows you the state of the page at the time you posted it.

If you don't want your message Label to retain its visible or text, markup should be  :

```
<asp:label id='myMsgLbl' runat='server' enableviewstate='false' visible='false/>'
```

--edit

As far as I know, the behavior with the back button is as expected.

Maybe you should look for solutions that allow disabling of the back button,

or disable caching of your form (but I guess this solution will be worse than your first problem)

```
    private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
        Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        Response.Expires = -1;
        Response.ExpiresAbsolute = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
```

Comment: also try setting this: Response.Cache.SetNoStore();